# Calculate SHA1 digest in Ruby of a Bignum

Tags: ruby, openssl, sha1, bignum, digest

I have this code in C that use openssl library to calculate the SHA1 digest of a bignumber.
How I can translate this code in Ruby?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int
main ()
{
    // Create a bignum = 3
    struct bignum_st *bn = BN_new ();
    BN_set_word (bn, 3);

    // Initialize SHA1 context
    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA_CTX sha_ctx;
    SHA1_Init (&sha_ctx);

    // Calculate SHA1 digest (in binary) of bignum 3
    SHA1_Update (&sha_ctx, bn, BN_num_bytes (bn));
    SHA1_Final (digest, &sha_ctx);

    // Print HEX value of digest
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
      printf ("%x", digest[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    // result is: 516b9783fca517eecbd1d064da2d165310b19759
}
```

Compile with: `gcc sha1.c -lcrypto`

Thx.

Comment: roll your own Ruby C extension? http://github.com/shyouhei/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT